# How do I run a .sh or .command file in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash

I've always wanted to be able to run a script I've downloaded online directly from the Finder but just double clicking the file does not work.

Answer (score 242):

Open Terminal, type in `sh /path/to/file` and press enter.

Faster is to type `sh` and a space and then drag the file to the window and release the icon anywhere on the window.

Comment: What do you think will happen if the shell script is written in another shell 's syntax, such as tcsh, zsh, or ksh? The suffix `sh` denotes a shell script not "run the script in this shell".

Comment: @fd0 The [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) will take care of that.

Comment: @user14492- When you invoke a shell script as `shell shell_script` the shebang line is ignored. The shell reads the first line as a comment.

Comment: @fd0, I don't understand. How is `sh /path/to/file` any semantically different from the alternative `/path/to/file.sh`?

Comment: @Pacerier- In the first form, the invoking user must be able to read the file and chooses which interpreter will read the file. In the second form, the file's permissions must be read and execute for the invoking user and the interpreter is determined by the hash bang on the first line of the script. In both cases the kernel does not interpret the suffix on the file.

Comment: I ran start command in .sh file i did this > sh filename.sh start

Answer (score 31):

Alternatively, you could also do

```
cd /directory/with/executable
chmod +x executable     # only required if your file is not already executable
./executable
```

which will also run the executable file with its specified shell (if specified in the shebang `#!/bin/(shell)`

Comment: In the question it says "run a script I've downloaded online". Files downloaded from the Internet usually have permissions set to 644.

Comment: @patrix i think it's not just internet, but every file that is copied from another filesystem onto yours because of the default mask in your account.

Answer (score 21):

```
chmod u+x myfile.sh
cp myfile.sh /usr/local/bin
```

edit `~/.bash_profile` and add the following line:

```
alias myfile=./myfile.sh
```

execute the following command-line:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

then you will be able to run your file as a program

`$ myfile`

Comment: in Ubuntu any script in your path can be executed as long as you have `#~/bin/sh`, while in `OSX` the script should have `.sh` extension and an `alias` for each one of them. :-O

Answer (score 14):

Follow these steps to run the script files:

1. Right-click on the .sh file.
2. Hover over **Open With**.
3. Choose **Other...**.
4. You should be in the **Applications** folder. Open **Utilities** folder and select Terminal.app.
5. If you can't select Terminal.app, change the enabled applications from **Recommended Applications** to **All Applications**. It is at the bottom of the window.
6. If you want to open every `.sh` file with Terminal.app, tick **Always Open With**.
7. Press the **Open** button in the bottom right corner of the window.

Answer (score 7):

OP's question was how to run the script *in the Finder*. None of the Unix solutions above do this. The answer is to set the file's extension to .command, eg, script.command. Double-clicking it will start Terminal and execute the script. (Make sure permissions are set to be executable.)

Answer (score 4):

The reason it doesn't work after downloading is the file permissions don't allow it. To enable execute permissions, open Terminal and type
`chmod 755 /path/to/script`.
Instead of typing the full path, you can drag the script onto the Terminal window from Finder.
Then, to execute, just enter
`/path/to/script`.
Again, you can drag and drop the file onto the Terminal window. This syntax should execute the script using the correct shell as defined on the first line of the script.

Comment: My file .sh opens in the text editor I created the file with. How can I open it in Terminal instead? I've set the right permissions.

Comment: @bart you need to add the .command extension for executing a script within finder directly.